# Location services not updating when return to the pages

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm having an issue with the location services after turned on doesn't update the pages when return. Example like Happycow tracked location services are turned off and required to setting page to turn it on, the page will be auto listed nearby restaurant after return, I would like to know how to get this work.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import '../../../services/screenadapter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  var latitude = 'Getting Latitude..'.obs;
  var longitude = 'Getting Longtitude..'.obs;
  var address = 'Getting Address..'.obs;
  late StreamSubscription<Position> streamSubscription;
  late StreamSubscription<ServiceStatus> streamSubscriptionServiceStatus;
  late LocationSettings locationSettings;

  _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Get.defaultDialog(
          title: 'Location Services Disabled',
          middleText: 'You need to enable Location Services in Setting',
          confirm: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                print('Confirm');
                await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
                Get.back();
              },
              child: Text('Confirm')),
          cancel: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print('Cancel');
                Get.back();
              },
              child: Text('Cancel')));

      // return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    streamSubscription =
        Geolocator.getPositionStream().listen((Position position) {
      latitude.value = 'Latitude: ${position.latitude}';
      longitude.value = 'Longtitude: ${position.longitude}';
      getAddressFromLatLang(position);
    });

    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        forceAndroidLocationManager: true,
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
  }

  Future<void> getAddressFromLatLang(Position position) async {
    List<Placemark> placemark =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    Placemark place = placemark[0];
    address.value = 'GPS: ${place.name},${place.subLocality},${place.locality}';
  }

  RxList itemList = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Great Nature Vegetarian",
      "image": "images/greatnature.jpg",
      "Hours": "9am - 10pm",
      "quality": "good",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Nature Vegan",
      "image": "images/naturevegan.jpg",
      "Hours": "8.30am - 10pm",
      "quality": "good",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Love Vege Vegetarian",
      "image": "images/lovevege.jpg",
      "Hours": "9am - 8pm",
      "quality": "good",
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Namasthe Vegetarian",
      "image": "images/namasthe.jpg",
      "Hours": "9am - 8.30am",
      "quality": "good",
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Organic Vegetarian Fresh Mart",
      "image": "images/organic.jpg",
      "Hours": "8am - 9.30am",
      "quality": "good",
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Sweet Garden Vegetarian",
      "image": "images/sweetgarden.jpg",
      "Hours": "9.10am - 10pm",
      "quality": "good",
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Tian Xin Vegetarian",
      "image": "images/tianxin.jpg",
      "Hours": "9am - 10pm",
      "quality": "good",
    },
  ].obs;

  Row headerBottomBarWidget() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: (() {
            Get.toNamed('/search');
          }),
          child: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget headerWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      // color: Colors.blue,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Good Day",
              style: GoogleFonts.notoSansJavanese(
                  fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(150),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  color: Colors.white
                  // color: Colors.white
                  ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text("Welcome back!",
                      style: GoogleFonts.notoSansJavanese(
                          fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(85),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Colors.white)),
                  Obx((() => Text(address.value,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: GoogleFonts.notoSansJavanese(
                          fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(40),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Colors.white
                          // color: Colors.white
                          ))))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView listView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: itemList.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(ScreenAdapter.width(8), 0,
            ScreenAdapter.width(8), ScreenAdapter.width(15)),
        child: Container(
          width: ScreenAdapter.width(1080),
          height: ScreenAdapter.height(300),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromARGB(184, 252, 249, 249),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    offset: Offset(1.0, 5.0),
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                    spreadRadius: 2.0)
              ]),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: ScreenAdapter.width(380),
                // color: Colors.red,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("${itemList[index]['image']}"),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    ScreenAdapter.width(8), 0, ScreenAdapter.width(8), 0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text("${itemList[index]['name']}"),
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
                          size: 13.0,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text("${itemList[index]['Hours']}"),
                    const Icon(Icons.star_border_outlined)
                  ],
                ),
              ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // final count = 0.obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _determinePosition();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Location Permission and Location Service (Only in Android) are different things.

Location service checks whether Android users have activated the location setting from the settings at the top of the device, that is, if serviceDisabled, you should not call openLocationSettings, only if the location permission is foreverDenied, you should use openLocationSetting.

Using AppLifecycleState, you can detect whether the user returns to the application after sending them to the application's location settings and take action.

Here is an example for AppLifecycleState
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AppLifecycleListener-class.html

OR

You can use `WidgetsBindingObserver`(mixin)

```
final class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleWidget> createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:

        /// Do something when the app is resumed
        /// (for example, when the user returns to the app)
        ///

        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing , the code is really saved me , TQ